# Python find double letters

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get all 3 letter words. They end with double letters and start with the letter 'a'.

> Like: app, add, all, arr, aoo, aee

I tried this but It doesn't work very well...

```
words =re.findall(r" a(\w)\1* ",text)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using

```
words =re.findall(r" a(\w)\1* ",text)
```

and here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vB9nA6/1) of it.

You can see an improvement by using a word boundary and as well as a specific limit of matches in your search [here](https://regex101.com/r/vB9nA6/)

```
\ba(\w)\1{1}\b
```

as you want **1 and only 1** additional instances of the matched `\w`, achieved with the `{1}` which only allows `1` of the match, i.e., `\1` which is an additional `\w`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use `+` instead of `*`:

```
words = re.findall(r"\ba(\w)\1+\b", text)
```

Otherwise you will match things with non-double letters. Also use `\b` to detect word boundaries.